# Getting Percentage value to show in the correct format

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets with data from different sources. I need to copy the data to a single worksheet and remove duplicates. To achieve this objective, I need all the data formatted the same on both worksheets. All of this is already coded except with one column of data I am having issues. These columns contain a representation for percentage. In worksheet A, the value is showing as .4386 which equates to 43.86%. I use this code that converts the value without issue:

`Worksheets("Verification").Range("F2:F2000").NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

In worksheet B, the same data is shown as 43.86, but the above code changes it to 4386.00%. I also tried changing this line to `.NumberFormat = "General\%"` and this almost works, but returns a value of 44%. What do I need to add to my code to get this to show 43.86% on worksheet B?

Comment: `.NumberFormat = "General%"` works for me.

Comment: @user1274820 Ok. I have two things to add here. First, (and I never knew this until now), the width of the column matters. I expanded the width and it does show 43.86%. However, Some of the other cells in the column have data that shows as 25.1%. I need this to show as 25.10%. I need to maintain two decimal points. How can I do that with `.NumberFormat = "General\%"` without having to apply a format to the cells?

Comment: Try `0.00\%` if they are already in percentage format. Otherwise, use `0.00%`. You can determine this like Ralph said, by checking to see if they are less than one, or if you already know how the sheets are formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the slow reply in comments - I will just submit an answer.

Like Ralph said, it's really better to make sure they are the same number.

`43.1` and `.431` are not the same number.

```
For Each c In [A1:A10]
    If c.Value < 1 Then
        c.Value = c.Value * 100
    End If
    c.NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
Next c
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: When I tried this I received a Variable not defined error that pointed to "c".

Comment: The code is just an example. You will want to loop through the ranges and modify the data accordingly. I don't know if your ranges are variable or how they're setup. If it's `F2:F2000` you would want to use that instead of `[A1:A10]`.

Comment: I was able to get this to work and I am now getting the required results. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You are stating that .4386 on worksheet A `is the same data [...] as` 43.86 on worksheet B. So, Excel is correct to convert 43.86 to 4386.00%. Maybe you need a conditional formatting: when the number is smaller or equal to 1 then format it `"0.00%"` and otherwise format it as `"0.00""%"""`.

Yet, I would assume that you'll be running into problems when comparing the data between the sheets with this solution. Hence, I would divide all numbers on sheet B by a 100 first to really make them comparable.

Note, that just by making numbers "look alike" they are not the same. Example: write in cell A1 the value 1000 and in cell B1 also 1000. Then change the number format for A1 to `0` and the number format for B1 to `0,` (or to `0.` outside the US). A1 will show `1000` while B1 will show `1`. If you ask in cell C1 `=A1=B1` you will get a `TRUE` as the answer.

Comment: I did state this incorrectly. The two worksheets (A & B) are from two different groups that wanted to see 43.86% in different formats for their own purposes. Group A needed it to show as .4386, and group B needed it to show as a whole number (43.86). My goal is to get these two sets of numbers into the format I need to compare all data from the two worksheets on one worksheet. This is one of the columns that will be compared (there are 10 total values that I will be comparing against, but this is the only one where the two groups formatted the value differently).